# How to open properties bar, I accidentally closed it?

Tags: properties

[image]

As you can see I accidentally closed my properties bar on the right hand side and I can't figure out how to open it again. Please help!

[image]

I mean the part I have boxed in red in this one I can't get that one reopened in my current project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the cursor on this point, you'll see your mouse will become a cross
[image]

Pull the cursor up and you'll see a new window opening like that

[image]

Last step: click on this one 
[image]

and change to properties

[image]

Answer (score 9):

By default it's toggled with <kbd>N</kbd> key