# How to view the Property Editor in Blender

Tags: interface

I am a beginner to blender and have somehow managed to hide the property editor in blender. Is there any way I can bring it back? Thanks

[image: My Blender Layout]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47364/how-to-open-properties-bar-i-accidentally-closed-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: As @Jachym Michal points out, it is possible that the 3d view is maximized - use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to toggle maximization.

If that does not fix the issue, perhaps you have indeed closed the other editors. All editors can be restored and rearranged as desired.

To add a new space, right-click the border of your existing space.

[image: Splitting the view]

Then select "Vertical split" and specify the split location by clicking. You will now have a new editor. To change the editor type to properties, click the dropdown at the top-left corner of the editor and select the desired editor type:

[image: Selecting editor type]

Comment: Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to get the Property Editor panel back in case it has been closed inadvertently:

1. Create a new panel and make it a Property Editor:

   - Move your mouse to a rounded corner of an editor panel's header e.g. the Outliner.
   - When the mouse pointer changes to crosshairs click-drag down (or up or left in case of other panels) to create a new editor panel.
   - Now press Shift F7 to make it a Property Editor, or choose Property from the Editor Type drop-down on the upper-left corner on the new editor header.
2. Load the Factory Settings

   - Go to the main menu and choose File > Defaults > Load Factory Settings
   - Click Load Factory Settings in the popup that appears

Caution: the second approach will reset any changes you have made to the user interface and the preferences of Blender, but it removes all the beginner tweakings that happened inadvertently.

Comment: Hello :). While this is is all true, adding new editors does't work when one of them is maximized. I think that was the main issue.

Comment: @Jachym Michal: I agree.